# TypeError: $(...).autocomplete is not a function

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I am getting the error `TypeError: $(...).autocomplete is not a function` when using the following code inside a `Drupal` module.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
        $("#search_text").autocomplete({
            source:results,
            minLength:2,
            position: { offset:'-30 0' },  
            select: function(event, ui ) { 
                    goTo(ui.item.value);
                    return false;
            }        
    }); 
});
```

jQuery is definitely loaded, and I have tried using a different variable for $ - any ideas what else might be the problem?

**(Edit) Drupal specific answer for autocomplete:**

```
drupal_add_library('system', 'ui.autocomplete');
```

Comment: Is jQueryUI loaded?

Comment: autocomplete is a jQuery-UI function, isn't it? Are you loading the necessary files for that, as well?

Answer (score 81, accepted):

you missed jquery ui library.  Use CDN of Jquery UI or if you want it locally then download the file from [Jquery Ui](http://jqueryui.com)

```
<link href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="Stylesheet">
<script src="YourJquery source path"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/jquery-ui.js" ></script>
```

Comment: Not working, I included all the library using npm in my package.json file. But still showing this error 
Uncaught TypeError: $(...).autocomplete is not a function
    at HTMLInputElement.<anonymous> (index.js:491)
    at HTMLInputElement.dispatch (jquery.js:5226)
    at HTMLInputElement.elemData.handle (jquery.js:4878)

Comment: Just had one of those moments when you wish you had the option to give bounty to an answer later. Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

Simple solution:
The sequence is really matter while including the auto complete libraries:

```
<link href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="Stylesheet">
<script src='https://cdn.rawgit.com/pguso/jquery-plugin-circliful/master/js/jquery.circliful.min.js'></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/jquery-ui.js" ></script>
```

Answer (score 3):

In my exprience I added two Jquery libraries in my file.The versions were jquery 1.11.1 and 2.1.Suddenly I took out 2.1 Jquery from my code. Then ran it and was working for me well. After trying out the first answer. please check out your file like I said above.

Answer (score 1):

Just add these to libraries to your project:

```
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

Save and reload. You're good to go.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code, Let $ be defined

```
(function ($, Drupal) {

  'use strict';

  Drupal.behaviors.module_name = {
    attach: function (context, settings) {
        jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
      $("#search_text").autocomplete({
          source:results,
          minLength:2,
          position: { offset:'-30 0' },  
          select: function(event, ui ) { 
                  goTo(ui.item.value);
                  return false;
          }        
        }); 
        });
   }
  };
})(jQuery, Drupal);
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I include an extra jquery library from TAMPERMONKEY script! Disable the script and it works.

Answer (score 0):

These Links aren't Working.
My View Cdn's are These.

```
<!--AutoComplete-->
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: This is more a comment than an answer