# onclick autocomplete field display all datas

Tags: javascript, jquery, autocomplete

Here is my code,

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">

 $("#autocomplete").focus(function () {
 $("#autocomplete").autocomplete("search", " ");
 });
```

I want to display all datas from the source while click on the autocomplete field. Now I am using the above code. By using this, The error showing like

> "`TypeError: $(...).autocomplete is not a function".

It's working fine when search with a keyword (ex: an). This error is showing while click on the autocomplete field only. Otherwise, It's working fine.  Please help me.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [TypeError: $(...).autocomplete is not a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16300586/typeerror-autocomplete-is-not-a-function)

Comment: Yes I included the files, <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>,
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>,
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">. Then what's the wrong

Comment: Does the code inside document ready?

Comment: I resolved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$("#autocomplete").autocomplete({
    /* options, events... */
}).focus(function () {
    $(this).autocomplete("search");
});
```